# Create custom block in drupal 8

Tags: block, drupal-8, drupal-blocks

[image]
**Custom Block** Create button does not have in Block layout. 
 Please see upper image.

[image]

I create testing block in **drupal 8**. But "Create Custom Block" button does not show in Block Layout. It only shows in Custom Block library.
 When I create the custom block, it does not appear in custom module list. 
 I'm a new in drupal 8. I used to create custom block in drupal 7 but it is easy. Please help me.

Comment: what's below demonstrate block region ? u need to have defined region so u can place your blocks in it

Comment: I create "TestBlock" . After that I find that block in block layout but I did not see that block. :(

Answer (score 3):

Once your block is created (I can see you created 2 bocks in your example). You need to go to "Block layout" and click "Place block" in the region you want:

[image]

A popup will appear. Use the filter to easily find you block and click "Place block" then click "Save block" and you block will appear in the region you chose.

[image]

Comment: my test blocks do not appear in block list. So that I could not place the blocks.  :(

Comment: Can you screenshot when you click "place block" on the left region ?

Comment: In Block Layout Tab, that "TestBlock" should be appear , right? But, that block does not found. However, I found it just now. :D It appears in "Auto Hidden Blocks" . When I click that, I found my "TestBlock". Thanks @progzy .

Comment: If you click on "place block" it would appear as well. You re welcome.

Comment: Best answer. Solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused between **block plugin** and **block entity**. The entity you are creating using UI by going to the custom block library is a block entity. The value for this is saved on database and not in code base. Where as in order to create a custom block plugin, you need to write code in your custom module inside **src/Plugin/Block** folder.

After that you can place the block (both entity and plugin) using block layout's place block button at your desire place.
[image: Place Block Button]